# How to create global variables accessible in models via middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I'm currently getting the **request** object within my Django **models** using the following code:

```
request_user = None
for frame_record in inspect.stack():
    if frame_record[3] == 'get_response':
        request_user = frame_record[0].f_locals['request'].user
```

While this works I would like to know how to expose the request object in middleware that can be easily accessed directly in my models?

I know how to create middleware my question is what "can be" set in the middleware that the model has access to? I can only see request which cannot be accessed directly in a model. Does Django have a global variable setting per session or something along these lines?

Comment: You should almost certainly not be doing the kind of code introspection you're describing above. Why can't you just pass the user into the model method as an argument? Or put the user id into the session variables?

Comment: I need the request object. I need to know who is making the request and some META info from the request.

Comment: Why don't you pass the `request` object to your model ? I don't think setting something in the middleware is the right approach.

Comment: Ok well this sounds more like a helper function for a view (from which you could pass the request object) than a model method then..

Comment: I see,  that makes sense. I'm happy to accept and answer of, don't do this and there is a better way etc .... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to use the` request` at the time of `.save()`? Also are you using a `ModelForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct (and least error prone) way to do this is to simply create a new function that you call from your view and pass in the request along with whatever other parameters you need.

Typically you want to separate your concerns such that model methods should only really take basic atomic types (strings, dicts, lists, numbers, etc) or other model instances. Stuff that deals with requests and responses should be functions at the view layer, and stuff that is used to format in the templates are obviously template helper functions. This will help make things easier to refactor or redesign later on.

Globals are never the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is generally not the way to do it, sometimes there are reasons (we use managers on our models that only ever return objects the current user is allowed to see -- it wants to know the request, and we don't control the arguments the functions are called with).

We use [django-tls](https://github.com/aino/django-tls) to achieve this. It is a middleware that puts the request in a global.

But, generally speaking, your models should not know that something like HTTP exists, or make any assumptions about the user interface. Dependencies should ideally run only in one direction: views know that models exist, so models shouldn't know that views exist. You'll be glad you did this if you have to do the same stuff in Celery tasks, or management commands, or from random Python code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think setting something in the middleware is a good approach here.

If you just need to access the `request` object, then you should just pass the request to your model. There you can access the `request.user` and `request.META` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be implementing process_request() instead to set the variable.